# Saving an html form to a table?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I want a way to verify if a user has already connected their bank account.  What i have isn't saving to the table so i have no way to verify it from the db.

I want: I want to only save a stripe_account_id to the bankaccount table (which is a column) some way through the forms submit.  Have it be unique and allowed to be overridden

This is what I have done so far:

**Bank Account Controller:**

```
 def new
     unless current_user.stripe_token
     redirect_to new_user_stripe_account_path and return
  end

  begin

    @stripe_account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)

        @bank_account = BankAccount.new
        @stripe_account = StripeAccount.find(params[:stripe_account_id])

     rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        handle_error(e.message, 'new')

     rescue => e
        flash[:error] = e.message
      end
     end

  def create

    unless params[:token] && current_user.stripe_token
       redirect_to new_bank_account_path and return
    end

    begin

      token = params[:token]
      stripe_account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)

         stripe_account.external_account = params[:token]
         stripe_account.save

         flash[:success] = "Your bank account has been added!"
         redirect_to dashboard_path


       @bank_account = BankAccount.new(bank_account_params)
       @bank_account.save!

       rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
       flash[:error] = e.message

        rescue => e
        flash[:error] = e.message
        end
       end

   private

          def set_bank_account
            @bank_account = BankAccount.find(params[:id])
          end

          def bank_account_params
            params.require(:bank_account).permit()
          end

        end
```

**Routes:**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :stripe_accounts
  end

  resources :stripe_accounts do
    resources :bank_accounts
  end

  resources :bank_accounts
```

*Without having the resources by itself, i get an error: "no post /bank_accounts" --- before i realized i had no way to verify a user having a bankaccount connected, it wasn't nested*

**Here's the gist of the form:**

```
  <form action="/bank_accounts" method="POST" id="payment-form-1">
      <input type="hidden" name="token" />
          <label for="country">Country</label>
              <select id="country" class="form-control">
                  <option value="US">United States</option>
                  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
              </select>
          <label for="currency">Currency</label>
              <select id="currency" class="form-control">
                  <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
              </select>
          <label for="routing-number">Routing Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="routing-number" value="110000000" />
          <label for="account-number">Account Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account-number" value="000123456789" />
          <label for="account-holder-name">Account Holder Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account-holder-name" />
          <label for="account-holder-type">Account Holder Type</label>
              <select id="account-holder-type" class="form-control">
                  <option value="individual">Individual</option>
                  <option value="company">Company</option>
              </select>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :stripeToken, current_user.stripe_token -%>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :stripe_account_id, :value => @stripe_account_id %>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
             <div class="outcome">
              <div class="error"></div>
                <div class="success">
               Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
           </form>
```

**The form is then sent using javascript:**

```
<script>

  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_W1234567qTSqQJucPWU8kh');

  function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');

    // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();

  } else {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var bankAccountParams = {
    country: document.getElementById('country').value,
    currency: document.getElementById('currency').value,
    account_number: document.getElementById('account-number').value,
    account_holder_name: document.getElementById('account-holder-name').value,
    account_holder_type: document.getElementById('account-holder-type').value,
  }
  if (document.getElementById('routing-number').value != '') {
    bankAccountParams['routing_number'] = document.getElementById('routing-number').value;
  }

  stripe.createToken('bank_account', bankAccountParams).then(setOutcome);
});


</script>
```

**Ultimately**, I am simply wanting to save a reference to the bankaccount table so i know if an end user has filled out their bank account data yet and for view purposes to remind them they have already.

I would like to save to the bankaccount table the stripe_account.id (this is associated with a user in the stripeaccount table), this way ill know which users have already filled this out. (the bankaccount table has a stripe_account_id column, id, created_at, and updated_at).

Is there way to do this from the html form, from the javascript, etc.? Is my controller just wrong?

Comment: Proper formatting of your code would help

Comment: You should not expose `current_user.stripe_token` and `@stripe_account_id` to the user (via the form in hidden fields)

Comment: You `preventDefault()` on form submit and then `submit()` the form again, I highly doubt this would work, it would just create an infinite loop (look at the network tab, you should see a lot of requests to the Stripe API)

Comment: Yeah i don't think thats needed.  I originally put that there when i was testing and never tested without it yet (passing the hidden field for stripe token)

Answer (score 0):

To save the external accounts ids to the database, you would need to do `customer.sources.all(object: "bank_account")`, then get the id of each and save it to the associated StripeAccount (I guess) associated to the user (while making sure you are duplicating ids).

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/list

Personally I think you don't need to store the bank account ids in your database, you can just fetch it from Stripe when you need it.

Comment: I'm not referring to the id from stripe.  I want the id that rails would create and attach it to a stripe_account_id just to i know from the db side that a user has a bank account inputted into their stripe account.  but from my code, nothing is entering into my BankAccount table

Comment: It's `source.id`